# How do I convert the number returned by \ref{item} into a letter?

Tags: cross-referencing, counters

Here's an MWE to show basically what I'm doing.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\begin{document}
\makeatletter
\newcounter{gp@itemnum}\setcounter{gp@itemnum}{0}
\newcommand*{\gp@newprint@itemnum}{\refstepcounter{gp@itemnum}(\alph{gp@itemnum})}
\newcommand*{\gpnewitem}[1]{\gp@newprint@itemnum\label{#1}}
\newcommand*{\gpgetitemref}[1]{Item (\ref{#1})}
\makeatother

New item: \gpnewitem{test}
Ref new item: \gpgetitemref{test}
\end{document}
```

How do I get `\ref{#1}` to print a letter instead of a number?

Comment: What does the label `item` refer to?

Comment: A reference is not a number. It may contain formatting commands and other features like link specials. Take a look at package `refcount`. Also, provide a MWE, there might be a better way by generating the reference in the correct format in the first place.

Comment: @GustavoMezzetti I edited my question to answer your question.

Comment: @HeikoOberdiek I've edited my question to clarify that I'm just using the `\refstepcounter`, `\label`, `\ref` mechanism. I need to convert the `\ref` result to a letter.

Comment: Incomplete code snippets do not constitute a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228). Maybe, you have forgotten to correctly define `\thegp@itemcount`, e.g. `\renewcommand*{\thegp@itemcount}{\alph{gp@itemcount}}`.

Comment: @HeikoOberdiek Okay, I've realised my question was unnecessarily detailed in one way and not enough in another, so I've completely rewritten my question and included a MWE. Your comment is the perfect answer to my question. I've already tried it and it does exactly what I want. If you could put your suggestion in an answer, I could accept it. Thank you.

Comment: I've never fancied hexagonal wheels myself. I've always imagined I'd be in for a bumpier ride :-).

Comment: @cfr Would you care to elaborate?

Comment: It is hard to tell without knowing what you are trying to do, but I suspect you are trying to reinvent the wheel.

Comment: @cfr I find that jumping to conclusions is rather like riding on hexagonal wheels.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The LaTeX counter protocol uses `\the<counter>` to get the counter representation.
The default is `\arabic`, but the command can be redefined to get a letter instead:

```
\renewcommand*{\the@gpp@itemnum}{\alph{gp@itemnum}}
```

Then, also `\label` and `\ref` uses this representation:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\begin{document}
\makeatletter
\newcounter{gp@itemnum}\setcounter{gp@itemnum}{0}
\renewcommand*{\thegp@itemnum}{\alph{gp@itemnum}}
\newcommand*{\gp@newprint@itemnum}{\refstepcounter{gp@itemnum}(\thegp@itemnum)}
\newcommand*{\gpnewitem}[1]{\gp@newprint@itemnum\label{#1}}
\newcommand*{\gpgetitemref}[1]{Item (\ref{#1})}
\makeatother

New item: \gpnewitem{test}
Ref new item: \gpgetitemref{test}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]